# MYSQL If have other table not show first table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 table one is user table other is userLog table

User table

```
+-----+----------+-----------+--------+
| id  | firtname | user_id   | flag   |
+-----+----------+-----------+--------+
|  62 |      aaaa| 477183673 |      1 |
|  63 |     aaaa | 475957614 |      1 |
|  64 |     aaaa | 445874961 |      1 |
|  65 |     aaaa | 143484840 |      1 |
|  66 |     aaaa | 418110881 |      1 |
+-----+----------+-----------+--------+
```

User log table

```
+-----+-------+-----------+--------+
| id  | su_id | user_id   | action |
+-----+-------+-----------+--------+
|  62 |     3 | 477183673 |      1 |
|  63 |     3 | 475957614 |      1 |
|  64 |     2 | 445874961 |      1 |
|  65 |     1 | 143484840 |      1 |
|  66 |     1 | 418110881 |      1 |
+-----+-------+-----------+--------+
```

I want to make this if i choose su_id = 3 then show user table like this

```
+-----+----------+-----------+--------+
| id  | firtname | user_id   | flag   |
+-----+----------+-----------+--------+
|  64 |     aaaa | 445874961 |      1 |
|  65 |     aaaa | 143484840 |      1 |
|  66 |     aaaa | 418110881 |      1 |
+-----+----------+-----------+--------+
```

If user make any action than save userLog after that i want to not show on first table select for this i try some join thing but not working,

```
SELECT * 
FROM user u 
INNER JOIN userLog l 
ON u.user_id = l.user_id
WHERE su_id !=3;
```

After this i understand join is not working then i'm here to try other methods :)

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa97b1/2)

Comment: that time showing just su_id = 3  data

Comment: I'm sorry, I spoke too soon. From your examples, it would appear that the query you have written would return the results you are looking for.

Comment: what is sqID  in your join? I don't see it in your user table.

Comment: @isaace look User log table

Comment: your query has u.sqID. That is wrong according to the data presented to us.

Comment: @isaace sorry i saw now my problem on example please look now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your select to select only the columns you want:

```
SELECT u.* FROM user u //instead of SELECT * FROM 
INNER JOIN userLog l 
ON u.user_id = l.user_id
WHERE su_id !=3;
```

We don't have enough data to understand why the above is not working but maybe you can try joining it by `id` instead of user_id

```
SELECT u.* FROM user u //instead of SELECT * FROM 
INNER JOIN userLog l 
ON u.id = l.id
WHERE su_id !=3;
```

You can also try this `NOT IN`query

```
SELECT * FROM user  
where user_id not in 
(select user_id from userLog where su_id = 3 )
```

this shouldn't take any duplicates from your logs table.

Comment: This is showing many time same because when i say su_id != 3 it's showing me with other userlog yes not showing 3 but showing 2 and 2 thats why i say join is not working

Comment: we need more sample data to understand the issue. see my updated answer.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa97b1/2 look this i enter more data it's must be show just a3 a4 a5 because on user 3 not making any action on that users

Comment: see my 3rd query in my answer.

Comment: that fix my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT ID, FIRSTNAME, USER_ID,FLAG 
  FROM USER,USERLOG 
  WHERE USER.user_ID=USERLOG.user_ID AND SU_ID <>3;
```

or you can try it with your own query just:

```
SELECT ID, FIRSTNAME, USER_ID,FLAG 
FROM user u
INNER JOIN userLog l 
ON u.ID = l.id
WHERE l.su_id <>3;
```

Comment: Not working with join method because that time duplicate data

Comment: in that case I suggest you to go with my first method

Comment: not working also with first method showing many time same beucase on userLog i have other user action thats making problem

Comment: your English is not clear. Do you want to show all entries excluding id 3 or including id 3?